# How to debug with stdin redirection in Xcode4?

Tags: debugging, xcode4, stdin, io-redirection

I'm making a command-line program, and it accepts `stdin`. So I expect this usage.

```
my-program < sample-file
```

This works well. Problem is I have no way to specify `stdin` redirection in Xcode4. It has execution argument, but it doesn't support `stdin` redirection. It looks escaping all arguments.

How can I debug `stdin` redirection in Xcode4?

Comment: Would love to know too! Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize this question is ancient but in case someone else stumbles upon it: There's a workaround to redirecting `stdin` in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13006633/1924459