# How do I run my C program file on a text file through Xcode 7.0?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, text

I have a C program (`addfilexcode.c`) that compiles and runs perfectly fine on terminal.

1. Does anyone know how to add a simple text file (i.e. `sched.txt`) on to Xcode so I can run my C program on this `sched.txt`?
   I tried adding it into the "Products" folder already and it did not work.
2. Do I need a certain command on my C program to have it specifically go through this `sched.txt` file in Xcode?

`addfilexcode.c`:

```
/* purpose: filters some data replacing semicolons with tab chars
   input: text
   output: text with tabs in place of semicolons */

int main(){
    int c;  
    while( (c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c == ';' ) c = '\t';   /* replace */
        putchar(c);     /* send to output */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7629886/how-can-i-pipe-stdin-from-a-file-to-the-executable-in-xcode-4

Comment: Not helpful because you tried it and it doesn't work? Or because you don't understand how it applies? Or..?

Comment: Hey alan, sorry, I should be more explicit it says permission denied on my terminal when I tried to pipe it. Any ideas about what I can do? Thanks!